# Ограничение ОЗУ, выделяемой одному процессу

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер.
Столкнулся с неприятным ограничением ОЗУ, выделяемой одному процессу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программу генерирует `List<string>` со значениями от 1 до 50 000 000.

В итоге заполняется ОЗУ примерно на 1.5 Гб, и выдается исключение.
Но не понимаю, почему, ведь в системе еще свободно 4 Гб ОЗУ.
Система: Win 8.1 x64 Pro

P.S. Как-то на кибере читал, что при переполнении ОЗУ система выделяет еще место из файла подкачки. Но, как видите, и ОЗУ-то не заполняется.

Comment: А зачем извращаться и выедать всю оперативную память под лист?

Comment: Я в курсе, что это не правильно и не логично.  
Такой алгоритм, какие-то идиоты написали программу, база в которую импортируется в .txt, который весит несколько Гб!!! Да мало того - в .txt еще генерируются колонки по идиотскому алгоритму.

Так что по-другому никак.

Comment: @z668, такой файл явно надо построчно читать

Comment: Не могли бы вы сказать, для чего вам хранить в оперативной памяти столько однотипной информации?

Comment: Скомпилировал программу только под x64, лимит вроде бы пропал, нагрузил массив - система отожрала 5 Гб озу.

Comment: ты генерируешь по одному ключу или по предыдущим?

Comment: В каком палане по ключу? List.Add() в цикле for, с каждой интерацией в массив заносится новое string занчение.

Comment: @z668

1. Прочесть построчно и сгенерировать массив колонок.
2. Читать еще раз.

Медленно, но избавляет от возможного "упирания в потолок".

> Скомпилировал программу только под x64, лимит вроде бы пропал

С этого надо было начинать.

Где-то тут недавно был вопрос, в ходе которого выяснили, что при простых операциях типа копирования список легко пожирает в два-три раза больше оперативки, чем в нем есть данных.

Comment: Проведите эксперимент. Перезагрузите комп, запустите программу на выполнение первый раз. Дайте ей отработать, закройте. Потом проделайте повторно данную операцию. Далее отпишитесь по результатам. Меня интересует следующее. Будет ли вылетать исключение при первом запуске программы после перезагрузки. А при последующих...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сабжу ответил Олег на кибере: [link](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1258738.html)

По List - сейчас проведу тесты.

Comment: @sp7, никаких исключений ни при первом, ни при последующих запусках. Памяти отжирает одинаково.

@Etki, а не припомните название темы или ссылку на нее?

Comment: @z668, не так уж и недавно, как оказалось.

http://hashcode.ru/questions/302748#302831